# In Pro*C language, what is the difference between VARCHAR and char

Tags: c, varchar, proc

Im new to Pro*C coding. is there any difference between VARCHAR and char? can i select a 
VARCHAR data into an character array? will there be any side effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `VARCHAR` is a special type added by the Pro*C pre-compiler, it doesn't exist in the base C language. However, in C you can access a `VARCHAR` variable as a structure if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch varchar data, example employee name(declared as varchar in table) into a character array ( char emp[10]) or I need to declare a VARCHAR variable and use it to fetch the data.

Comment: The Pro*C compiler does recognize the varchar type, but converts it to a structure automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Char represents one character while varchar represents a variable-length string(array of char).